# tsne callback function using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, callback

I would like to use `ggplot()` instead of `plot()` for the callback function of the 'tsen' package in R.

From the help

```
colors = rainbow(length(unique(iris$Species)))
names(colors) = unique(iris$Species)
ecb = function(x,y){ plot(x,t='n'); text(x,labels=iris$Species, col=colors[iris$Species]) }
tsne_iris = tsne(iris[,1:4], epoch_callback = ecb, perplexity=50)
```

`x` should be a matrix of 2 columns an N rows, where N is the number of rows of `iris[,1:4]` but I cannot figure how to make ggplot working on `x`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsne)

data(iris)

ecb <- function(x) {

  epoc_df <- data.frame(x,Species = iris$Species)

  plt <- ggplot(epoc_df,aes(x = X1, y = X2,label = Species,color = Species)) + geom_text()

  print(plt)
}

x <- tsne(iris[,1:4],epoch_callback = ecb, perplexity = 50,max_iter = 800)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is perfect.